# Map values in objects

Tags: swift, object

I have a model that looks like this:

```
struct Person {
    let id = 0
    let name = ""
    var comment = String()
}

struct OverAll {
    let person = [Person]
}
```

I have two objects:

```
OverAllPerson // contains 10 persons
OverAlPersonWithComments // contains 10 persons
```

These objects are exacley the same except that `OverAllPerson` does not have the comments

**Question:**
How do I add the comments from `OverAlPersonWithComments` to `OverAllPerson`? As I mentioned above the objects are identical except the `comments`.

I was thinking of using `map` but I´m not sure how to do it.

Comment: Why not just duplicate `OverAlPersonWithComments`, and use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, I'd just do a simple `for` loop

```
for index in 0 ..< peopleWithoutComments.count {
    peopleWithoutComments[index].comment = peopleWithComments[index].comment
}
```

---

The pattern you might be thinking of is `zip` with `map`. Consider:

```
let names = ["joe", "bill", "jane"]
let comments = [
    ["I like baseball", "But I don't like the Yankees"],
    ["I don't watch sports"],
    ["I like football", "I'm an Arsenal fan"]
]

struct Person {
    let name: String
    let comments: [String]
}

let people = zip(names, comments).map { (name, comments) in Person(name: name, comments: comments) }
```